# Async receiving value from ibm mq with dynamic correlationId

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms, spring-webflux

I'm sending messages to ibm mq with some correlationId (unique for each message). Then I want to read from output queue this concrete message with specific correlationId, and i want it to be non-blocking to use it in java webflux controller.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without lot of pain? Options like jmsTemplate.receiveSelected(...) is blocking, while creating a bean implementing interface MessageListener doesn't provide a way to select message by dynamic selector(i.e. correlationId is unique for each message).

Comment: I'm working on a same problem. Did you manage to solve yours?

Answer (score 1):

You could use spring `MessageListener` to retrieve all messages and connect it with controller by `Mono.create(...)` and your own event listener which trigger result Mono

```
// Consumes message and trigger result Mono
public interface MyEventListener extends Consumer<MyOutputMessage> {}
```

Class to route incoming messages to correct MyEventListener

```
public class MyMessageProcessor {
    // You could use in-memory cache here if you need ttl etc.
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyEventListener> REGISTRY
            = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void register(String correlationId, MyEventListener listener) {
        MyEventListener oldListeer = REGISTRY.putIfAbsent(correlationId, listener);
        if (oldListeer != null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Correlation ID collision!");
    }

    public void unregister(String correlationId) {
        REGISTRY.remove(correlationId);
    }

    public void accept(String correlationId, MyOutputMessage myOutputMessage) {
        Optional.ofNullable(REGISTRY.get(correlationId))
                .ifPresent(listener -> listener.accept(myOutputMessage));
    }
}
```

Webflux controller

```
private final MyMessageProcessor messageProcessor;

.... 

@PostMapping("/process")
Mono<MyOutputMessage> process(Mono<MyInputMessage> inputMessage) {
    String correlationId = ...; //generate correlationId

    // then send message asynchronously

    return Mono.<MyOutputMessage>create(sink ->
            // create and save MyEventListener which call MonoSink.success
            messageProcessor.register(correlationId, sink::success))
            // define timeout if you don't want to wait forever
            .timeout(...)
            // cleanup MyEventListener after success, error or cancel
            .doFinally(ignored -> messageProcessor.unregister(correlationId));
}
```

And into `onMessage` of your JMS `MessageListener` implementation you could call

```
messageProcessor.accept(correlationId, myOutputMessage);
```

You could find similar example for Flux in the [reactor 3 reference guide](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create)